# xsl file Access Denied except on host machine

Tags: delphi, xslt, delphi-2009

Here is an example of the start of an XML file we build, note that is is Accessing "CCD.xsl" for the style sheet.

```
'<?xml version="1.0"?>'
'<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="' + 'C:\CDA\Schemas\CCD.xsl"?>'
'<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'
```

Anytime this xml loaded into a TWebBrowser from a remote user accessing the server they get the following error

"Access is denied. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/CDA/Schemas/CCD.xsl'."

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(TempFileName);  //TempFileName = C:\data\CCR_Record_3336557.xml
```

Any Ideas on how this could be resolved?

If you need additional information let me know..

Thanks, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems, both stemming from the fact that the XSL reference is to a local file on the C drive.

Problem #1 (the one giving you the error) is that your browser is blocking attempts to access local file system resources from a remotely-downloaded XML file. So the browser throws a security error when trying to render that XML file. That's the immediate error you're seeing. Adjusting security settings or changing browsers won't solve your problem because of problem #2.

Problem #2 is that your client presumably doesn't have an XSL file on their local hard drive at `C:\CDA\Schemas\CCD.xsl`. It's on the C drive of the remote server. You can't just put it on a network share because of problem #1, so you'll need to serve it through the same mechanism you serve the XML file. Then change your URI for the XSL file to something like `http://myserver/schemas/ccd.xsl`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am still a little confused as to how I can resolve this though.  When you said "so you'll need to serve it through the same mechanism you serve the XSL file."  Did you mean XML file?  Can you give a small example to help me understand what needs to be done?  Thanks

Comment: Yeah, the XML file. You set the address for the TWebBrowser to something like `http://myserver/cda/filename.xml`, right? You'll need to retrieve the XSL from the same server via HTTP.

Comment: Well the TWebBrowser is actually loading the file via "WebBrowser1.Navigate(TempFileName);" to a xml file on the server i.e. C:\data\CCR_Record_3336557.xml do you think if the xsl file was located in the same folder it would fix it?

Comment: So.. How is the user remote then?

Comment: Sorry, lets see so we have this software we compiled in Delphi 2009.  And users run the ".exe" remotely on the server.  Within the software there is a TWebBrowser (delphi) component where we load the xml file which accesses the xsl file and errors out.  But if you just run the exe directly from the host machine it works..

Comment: I don't know if you would classify it as remotely, they just run the software on their computer from the exe on the server..

Comment: Right. They're running the software on their computer. So if you have a path to a file, that path has to be relative to the user's computer, not the server. Where the file is on the server's irrelevant. If the XML file is being opened off the user's local filesystem, and you put the XSL in the same directory, it should be fine.

Comment: Yep your right, it turns out the xml file was being accessed on the server and the xsl file was being accessed from the clients computer.  Got it fixed now.  Thanks